# how to make smooth css transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

how can i get a css transition example like in [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/01/css-transitions-101/) (the dropdown example), so far I've managed to only change the text and background color, but not the whole transition effect thing (where the rectangle rolls when hovered and rolls back smoothly when un-hovered), any idea how can i achieve it? here's my code:

```
a.menulink
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
background-color: rgb(235,235,185);
-webkit-transition: color .25s linear;
transition: color .25s linear;
transition: background-color .15s linear .1;
}

a.menulink:hover
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: rgb(255,24,24);
-webkit-transition: color .25s linear, background-color .15s linear .1s;
transition: color .25s linear, background-color .15s linear .1s;
}
```

thank you before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[See this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52uta/3/)**

```
<a href="#" class="linkhover">
    <span hover-title="LINK HOVER">LINK HOVER</span>
</a>

.linkhover {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 400px;
    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.linkhover span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.linkhover:hover span {
    transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -35px ) rotateX( 90deg );
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -35px ) rotateX( 90deg );
}
.linkhover span:after {
    content: attr(hover-title);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
    background: red;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
}
```

Comment: Anytime..but do read this for better understanding of css perspective in 3d animatioin with css.. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but it seems not compatible with chrome, any suggestion?

Comment: I checked it in chrome mac v28 and its working fine.. check again here http://jsfiddle.net/52uta/1/

Comment: as i checked it now, it doesn't work on IE, any workaround for it? thanks :)

Comment: so i was supposed to add like {-ms-webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );} for IE to work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Just use this. No need use transition in ":hover" selector.

```
a.menulink{
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
background-color: rgb(235,235,185);
-webkit-transition: color .25s linear;
transition: color .25s linear;
transition: background-color .15s linear .1s;
}

a.menulink:hover
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: rgb(255,24,24);}
```